# When to use std::invoke instead of simply calling the invokable?

Tags: c++, std, c++17

As I understand, `std::invoke` allows me to do something like:

```
std::invoke(f, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Is there a scenario when it's more advantageous than simply doing:

```
f(arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If the invocable is a pointer to a member function, then you need to do one of  these:

```
(arg1->*f)(arg2,...);
(arg1.*f)(arg2,...);
```

Depending on what `arg1` is.

[INVOKE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) (and its official library counterpart `std::invoke`) was pretty much designed to simplify such messes.

You'd use `std::invoke` to support the caller of your code passing *any* callable, and not having to adapt their call site with a lambda or a call to `std::bind`.

Comment: Nice, I see. I guess that also mean that without invoke I will need different code for a member function and a free function. Is that right?

Comment: @EladWeiss - Yup. We either had to write a bunch of specializations or re-implement INVOKE ourselves (and imagine supporting smart pointers as well, yikes). The new utility is a library writers tool.

Comment: @EladWeiss Have a look at a [sample implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) of `std::invoke` and then be grateful that you don't have to write that yourself :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 now imagine how would that look if `if constexpr` was not avaliable.

Comment: You never do `->*` with `INVOKE`. It always uses `.*`.

Comment: @T.C. - I imagine that's how support for "smart pointer like" classes is obtained?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Note that we cheated with that implementation by assuming the availability of `invoke_result_t` and `is_nothrow_invocable`; the former is particular crucial for making `invoke` SFINAE-friendly. In practice, these would likely be powered by the same underlying machinery, which would need to be more complex. @StoryTeller correct.

Comment: @T.C. - And BTW I never said `INVOKE` does that, I only said the OP's code would have to support both of these use-cases somehow.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot It would look like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/utility/functional/invoke&oldid=92023#Possible_implementation) :)

Comment: @T.C. - But doesn't the uniform treatment of pointer to members places certain limitations on the arguments? I mean, granted an overloaded `operator ->*` is rarely seen in the wild. But I could imagine someone wanting to send a "locking handle" as the operand to invoke. We could wrap that mess in a lambda instead, but still.

Comment: @StoryTeller Huh?  I'm not sure I understand your question. `INVOKE` does either `(arg1.*f)(arg2...)` or `((*arg1).*f)(arg2...)`. `->*`, overloaded or not, simply doesn't come into play (and `.*` is not overloadable).

Comment: @T.C. - Yes, I understand it doesn't. My point being that people may rarely have reason to overload it. And it not coming into play may require non-trivial adaptation of their code.

Comment: Overloaded for a pointer to member of some class, without the LHS actually being a smart pointer? That seems rather unlikely even in the unlikely world of `->*` overloads.

Comment: @T.C. - [Classes akin to this](https://ideone.com/qh3UCh), while not being smart pointers, implement `operator->` (and they are somewhat in use). One could after much labor replicate the behavior with `operator->*`... Though now that I think of the work required to achieve this, it does indeed seem a very unlikely use-case.

Answer (score 13):

`std::invoke` can be useful when you create a lambda and need to call it immediately. It the lambda is big, parentheses after it can be hard to observe:

```
[] (/* args */) {
    // many lines here
    // ...
} (/* args */)
```

vs

```
std::invoke(
    [] (/* args */) {
        // many lines here
        // ...
    },
    /* args */);
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to add on top of the two answers, one is giving a good theoretical explanation and the other is trying to provide a concrete example. Here is a good reason of why does `std::invoke` makes things better.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    void echo(){std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;};
};

int main()
{
    ////
    // Vanilla version of invoking .echo()
    foo(f);
    f.echo();

    ////
    // Pointer to *class* member function version
    void (foo::* pf)() =  &foo::echo;
    foo obj;
    
    (obj.*pf)();    // ugly
    // instead do ...
    std::invoke(pf, obj);

    // obj->echo(); <-- does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now the question of why would you use/need a pointer to a class member function is a different topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
template< class Callable, typename ... Args>{}

    //f(args...);   // if arg1 is a class object pointer 
                    // we should use it like this(arg1.*f)(args...); 

    std::invoke(f, args...); //  now  every thing is ok
}

void foo(char c) {
    std::cout << "foo called\n";
}

int main()
{
    struct S {
        int f1(char c) {
            std::cout << "S::f1 called\n";
        }
        void operator()(char c) {
            std::cout << "S::operator() called\n";
        }
    };
    int (S:: * fptr)(char c) = &S::f1;
    S  obj;

    dosomething(fptr, obj, 'a');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer